# C# Deployment: How to have config files after deployment?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, deployment

In my C# Windows form application (Visual Studio 2012 )I want to have some kind of config file, that right after deployment the users can change its content and the app will use changed values. This works perfect during development stage. After deploying the application my config file removed to %.. ../appdata/.. %. How can I do it, that after deployment I have that configfile in deployed folder?

I have found myself: right click on the file and set the property to content. With that file will be automatically included.

Answer (score 1):

Just right click on the file and set file property to content. With that the file will be automatically included

Answer (score 0):

In the config file properties in Visual Studio, set:

Copy to output directory: **Copy always**

Comment: This doesnot work as well. I have added my created "filename.ini" file , added to my project and changed the property of that file to always copy, but after deploying again file was not with deployed files

Comment: When you say deployment, are you using Clickonce or something else?

Comment: I am just using Project->publish with default project settings.

Comment: If so, Under Publish settings, check the "Application Files' button. You will be able to choose which files in your project are copied, and select your configuration file.

Comment: No sorry, but I have found myself, just right click on the file and set the file property to content, and Done.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for deployment?
If you use the Installshield lite project type then you can specify where the app.config file is deployed to.

Comment: I don't want to use app.config file, but instead in my code I have written something like this: if file doesn't exist create "programmname.ini" file where I store some values and use these values. Now I want this file to be appear in the same folder where the app will be installed (after deployment). But after deployment I do not have this file in ...%appdata% windows junction folder